# How to clear multiple local variables in powershell

Tags: powershell, shell

I think we can do this
Clear-Variable -Name Facility_Name, StudentDOB, StudentLastName

However i have around 200 variables that needs to be cleared after the foreach loop, wanted to know if there is a easy way to clear all these local variables in one shot?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code and whatever you have tried so far

Comment: i suspect that you are doing things wrongly when creating so very many variables. for instance, you list values that SHOULD be stored in  _properties of an object_. instead of `$StudentDOB` one likely otta use `$Student.DOB` - note the dot delimiting the variable `$Student` and the property `DOB`.

Comment: Yes, for your custom variables. Get in the habit of adding a prefix them with say 2-3 chars. Say, using the first 3 of your name. So, like  'sanSomeVariableName', then clear or remove them using 'san*'.

Comment: To compliment, @Lee_Dailey's, I would probably use a hash table: `$Student = @{}`; `$Student['DOB'] = 'my DOB'`. Anyways, please **show the code in the question**, so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) and [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) make sensible **recommendations regarding *avoiding a large number of variables* to begin with**:

- Collect multiple values in [*arrays*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) rather than in individual variables.
- Alternatively, for *named* access, create multiple values as named (keyed) entries of a single [*hashtable*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) object or as properties of a single [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_object_creation?view=powershell-7.1#create-custom-objects-from-hash-tables) instance.

To address the question as asked:

---

Note that [`Clear-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Clear-Variable) only resets the *values* of variables to `$null`, it doesn't actually remove *the variables themselves*.

**To remove *variables* as a whole, use [`Remove-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Remove-Variable).**

Both cmdlets:

- accept [wildcard patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) as arguments for the `-Name` parameter; pattern `*` is the one that matches *all* names.
- have a `-Scope` parameter that specifies the scope whose variables to target, namely `Global`, `Script`, `Local`, or a *numbered* scope where `0` is the same as `Local`, `1` is the *parent* scope, `2` is the grandparent scope, and so on.

[postanote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote) suggests using a *shared name prefix*, say `foo_`, for those variables you want to remove all at once, which then allows you to call something like:

```
Remove-Variable -Scope Local foo_*
```

---

Taking a step back: **If there's a block of code with variables that you want to restrict to that block, simply use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) and invoke it with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)**, which **runs the script block in a *child* scope** whose variables go out of scope when execution of the block ends; e.g.:

```
# Any variables created inside the { ... } block executed 
# with & are scoped to that block.
& {
  foreach ($i in 1..3) {
    $j = $i
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.Clear-Variable -Scope Script variablename

Comment: @Razz, to recap from the answer: `Clear-Variable` only _resets the variable's value_ (to `$null`), it doesn't _remove the variable_.